# Passing image to another viewcontroller without changing view

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiviewcontroller

I am making a greeting cards app. There are three view controllers. In the **first** view, I have some images. Choosing an image should set that image as the background in the **third** view controller. The **first** view has a *continue* button that takes us to the **second** view and another *continue* button in the **second** view will take us to the third view. Now we should be able to see the background image of the **third** view as the image selected in the **first** view. How can this be done??

This is my code:

*ViewController.h* (First view)

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    GreetingCard *theme;  

    IBOutlet UIImageView *Bday_1;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *Bday_2;

}

@property (nonatomic , retain) GreetingCard *theme;

- (IBAction)themeSelect:(UIButton *)sender ;

@end
```

*ViewController.m*

```
- (IBAction)themeSelect:(UIButton *)sender {

    if (sender.tag == 0) { 
        self.theme.passedImage = Bday_1.image;  //Passing the image to the second view       
    }

    if (sender.tag == 1) {
        self.theme.passedImage = Bday_2.image;
    }
}
```

*GreetingCard.h*  (Third view)

```
@interface GreetingCard : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIImageView *background;
    UIImage *passedImage;
}

@property (nonatomic , retain) UIImage *passedImage;

@end
```

*GreetingCard.m*

```
- (NSString *) saveFilePath {  

    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    return [[path objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savefile.plist"];  

}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application { 

NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: background.image,nil];  
[values writeToFile:[self saveFilePath] atomically:YES];

}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    background.image = passedImage; //The background image is set as the passedImage, which is the image chosen by the user in the first viewcontroller


/*** Loading the saved data ***/

    NSString *myPath = [self saveFilePath];

BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPath];

if (fileExists)
{

    NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myPath];
    background.image = [values objectAtIndex:0];

}

UIApplication *myApp = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground:)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                           object:myApp];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure of your view hierarchy.

If they all live on the same parentView controller and they are contained:
- Use a custom protocol and delegate to notify the corresponding controller to do an action.

If you are using a navigationController as parent:

- Create a custom init for the second view controller, storing the
  image name. Push the second view controller on the navigation stack.
- Create a custom init for the third view controller, storing
  the image name to display, obtained from the second view controller. Push the third view controller on the navigation stack.
- On the third view controller viewDidLoad, set the stored image as the background.

About Protocols:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html

About navigation controllers:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a private property on `ViewControllerA` to store the selected image.
2. Go to the `segue` on the storyboard for the continue button and give it a descriptive name (for example "segueContinue").
3. Create a public property on `ViewControllerB` to store the selected image (the baackground).
4. Override the `prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender` method.  Instantiate the destination view controller as a `ViewControllerB`, and set the property on B to match the selected property from A.
5. In your `viewDidLoad` on the second view, (or `viewWillAppear` is probably better), set the background image to the image you put in the property.

---

In the first view controller's `.m` file, add these lines:

```
@interface ViewController()
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImage *selectedImage;
@end
```

Above the `@implementation`.

Whenever the user selects an image, that image should be assigned to `self.selectedImage`.  Now, also add `@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImage *background;` to the `.h` of the second view.

Now:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender { 
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueContinue"]) { 
        GreetingCard *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.background = self.selectedImage;
    }
}
```

And you should be good to go (assuming you're doing everything properly in your second view controller's `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Err.. I am not using segues. I am just presenting the view modally from the code.

Comment: Are you using a storyboard?  And either way... if you're presenting the view modally from code, it'd be  helpful if you included that code.  But either way, you should probably be using storyboards and segues... they're significantly easier to work with (and you can have modal segues... and segues can be called programmatically).

Comment: Yes, I am using storyboard but I have literally no idea about segues as I have just recently started using Xcode. Can you please guide me in more detailed way?

Comment: It's as simple as click-dragging from one view controller (or a button on that view controller) to the view controller you wish to segue into.  Then you can give the segue a name for which to reference it in code so that it can be called programmatically.

Comment: Here is a good tutorial on segues: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50310/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-2 (and that particular tutorial looks like it's even using a modal segue)

Comment: Ok, I got it till this part:
`- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueContinue"]) {
        
        GreetingCard *vc = [segue destinationViewController];`

Not sure how to set the properties and pass them.

Comment: In the `viewDidLoad`, this is what I have got: `background.image = selectedImage;` I don't see the image being passed though. It's still an empty view.

Comment: Did you change these lines? `self.theme.passedImage = Bday_1.image;` to `self.selectedImage = Bday_1.image;`?

Comment: Yes, I did.. Followed all your instructions exactly!

Comment: I have edited the question for a slightly different requirement. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Did you ever get it working as originally posted...?

Comment: Nope.. I didn't.. The image is not being passed